# Questions about unsigned char, char, BYTE, and file writing

Tags: c++, string, file, vector

I have a vector defined as follows:

```
std::vector<char> contents;
```

My goal is to read a file into an array of BYTE, which is a typedef for unsigned char. My attempt is as follows:

```
BYTE rgbPlaintext[] = {0x00};

std::ifstream in;
std::vector<char> contents;

in.open("test.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (in.is_open())
{
    // get the starting position
    std::streampos start = in.tellg();

    // go to the end
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

    // get the ending position
    std::streampos end = in.tellg();

    // go back to the start
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // create a vector to hold the data that
    // is resized to the total size of the file    

    contents.resize(static_cast<size_t>(end - start));

    // read it in
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());

    BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;
}
```

But when I wrote rgbPlainText out to a file, using the following:

```
std::ofstream f("testOut.dat",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
for(std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = contents.begin(); i != contents.end(); ++i) 
{
    f << *rgbPlaintext;
}
```

It was just a line of nulls. The test.dat file contained legible text. How can I get this to work correctly? When I changed the vector to unsigned char instead of just char as it is defined now, I got an error in the "read it in" step, saying the expected argument type is char * while the entered argument is unsigned char *. So the questions are as follows:

1. Am I writing to the file correctly? If not, what is the correct way.
2. How can I convert a vector of char into a vector of unsigned char?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem here.  Where you say `BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;` you are declaring a variable named `rgbPlaintext` inside the curly braces that follow your `if` statement.  From the compiler's point of view, that isn't the same `rgbPlaintext` that you have declared at the beginning of your program.  And as soon as you assign a value to the second `rgbPlaintext`, you encounter the closing curly brace, which simply causes that value to be discarded.

The statement at the top should be

```
BYTE *rgbPlaintext;
```

and the last statement before the closing curly brace should be

```
rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;
```

*without* the `BYTE *` part.

That way, you will still have access to `rgbPlaintext` in the code following your `if` statement.

Comment: I removed the BYTE part and now it gives an error: Expression must be a modifiable value

Comment: It's important to note where the asterisks are. You first declaration should be `BYTE* rgbPlaintext;` instead of `BYTE rgbPlaintext[] = {0x00};`. Then the reference at the bottom of your `if` statement should just be a reference, instead of a definition, e.g., `rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;` instead of `BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;`.